# execute CMD command via VBA -shell

Tags: vba, excel, shell

Below is the example data availble in txt file

[image]

I want to extract the data in another txt file which Sr no is 1.

Please suggest me the VBA code which execute CMD command and bifurcate the data in another txt file.I have search the internet and got to know it is possible via use **Shell("  ").** help me to achieve my above object.

My txt file(i.e. file3) is available in Z:\ drive.

via below code i can open the cmd command window

```
Sub macro()
Call Shell("cmd.exe", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide any code you have tried thusfar. We are on SO to collaborate and help with coding, not a code-for-you service.

Comment: @Cyril Sir,I have updated the same in my query.

Comment: I don't get what you want to achieve with with the command window. If you are using VBA, why not read and write the textfiles withing VBA?

Comment: @FunThomas Dear Sir, VBA read and write will change the formatting and also as per my knowledge read data i can write in excel sheet only.i simply want to bifurcate data in txt file in same format same like main file.

Comment: If you know the file format, why not generate a `schema.ini` file for the file you want to read, and then query it with `sql` using an `adodb.connection` and an `adodb.recordset`?  Simplest option still to use a `FileSystemObject` and read/write from `VBA` itself though as @FunThomas suggests.

Comment: @sagar I'm sorry, but that's nonsense...  `VBA` can read the file exactly as it is without making changes to it just by using a `FileSystemObject`

Answer (score 0):

The Call Shell(,) command is what loads CMD.

If you want to load a file from the CMD, through VBA, you would use something such as:

```
Sub Open_CPT()
    Dim Loc As String
    Loc = "Z:/#CPT.bat"
    Call Shell(Loc, 1)
End Sub
```

This will open the file or item at that location.

Depending how you want to bifurcate/split your data, you might want to use the native function of Excel/VBA to open the file and delimit by spaces/tabs/etc.  You can then save as a .txt file, after modifications have been made how you want.

Comment: Note that the 1 in  (Loc,1) is equivalent to vbNormalFocus.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your guidance as per the instructions of **Dave** I have developed the below code with the help of `FileSystemObject` 
Please find the below solution.

```
Sub VBA()
Dim fr, t As String
Dim s As String

ReDim arr(500) As String
ReDim arri(500) As String

Dim i As Long
i = 0
ii = 0
Dim n As Integer


Dim fso
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

fr = "z:\file3.txt"

Set oFS = fso.OpenTextFile(fr)


Do While Not oFS.AtEndOfStream

arr(i) = oFS.ReadLine
sls = InStr(1, arr(i), 1, vbTextCompare)
If sls >= 1 Then
arri(ii) = arr(i)
ii = ii + 1
End If
i = i + 1
Loop

oFS.Close

n = FreeFile()

s = arri(0)
For ix = LBound(arri) + 1 To UBound(arri)
s = s & vbCrLf & arri(ix)
Next

Open "z:\file2.txt" For Output As #n
Print #n, s
End Sub
```